# how to retrieve data from mysql database and populate in list view in jquery mobile

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, jquery-mobile

please someone help me to find the solution for how to retrieve data from mysql database and populate in list view in jquery mobile.

am having the php code as follows

```
<? php

include('libraries/config.php');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from category") or die(mysql_error());
while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $arr[] = $obj;
}
echo json_encode($data);
echo '{"Deals":'.json_encode($arr).'}';

?>
```

here am getting the data from mysql in json format but i was not known how to populate this in listview, my html page is as follows

```
<div id="content-area" style="height:auto;">
    <br/>
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li>
            <a href="comfort_list.html">
                <div class="content-home-tab1">
                    <div class="img-content">
                        <img id="ic_home" src="images/next_btn.png"  style="margin-top:37px; margin-left:448px;" width="22"  height="28" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="content-home-p">
                        <b>Comfort</b>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li> 
            <a href="#">
                <div class="content-home-tab1">
                    <div class="img-content">
                        <img id="ic_home" src="images/next_btn.png"  style="margin-top:37px; margin-left:448px;" width="22"  height="28" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="content-home-p">
                        <b>Handling Your Lenses</b>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here in my code am giving static data to list that is comfort and handling your lens, am having this data in db and i need to get that and to be placed here.

in the page i am posting in a form like this

```
<form method="post" action="help.html">
        <ul data-role="listview" >

        <?php while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){

?>


                    <li>

        <a href="help1.php?id=<?php echo $row['categoryID']; ?>">
        <div class="content-home-tab1">
         <div class="img-content">
                            <img id="ic_home" src="images/next_btn.png"  style="margin-top:37px; margin-left:448px;" width="22"  height="28" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="content-home-p">
                           <b><?php  echo $row['title'];?>

</b>
                        </div></div></a>

                        </li>
                        <?php }?>


                        </ul>

                        </form>
```

and in another page am trying to get the id as follows

```
<?php
include('libraries/config.php');
$getID = $_GET['id'];
echo $getID;
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * from category where categoryID ='$_GET['id']'");

$stmt->execute();

?>
```

but when going to that page it is showing nothing and when refreshed then it is showing so that only am asking how to get it to fetch data and print it when the page is loaded. thanks.

Comment: please someone help me with some solution please

Comment: why no one is answering to my question?

Comment: What does you JSON data look like? can you paste it please...

Comment: [{"categoryID":"comfort","title":"Comfort","tips":"[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\",\"4\",\"5\",\"6\",\"7\",\"8\",\"9\",\"10\",\"11\",\"12\",\"13\",\"14\",\"15\",\"16\",\"17\",\"18\",\"19\",\"20\",\"21\",\"22\",\"23\",\"24\"]"},{"categoryID":"dryness","title":"Dryness","tips":"[\"45\",\"46\",\"47\",\"48\",\"49\",\"50\",\"51\",\"52\",\"53\",\"54\",\"55\",\"56\"]"},{"categoryID":"eyesight","title":"Vision","tips":"[\"68\",\"69\",\"70\",\"71\",\"72\",\"73\",\"74\",\"75\",\"76\",\"77\",\"78\",\"79\",\"80\",\"81\",\"82\",\"83\",\"84\",\"85\"]"}]} this is how my json data looks like

Comment: So basically you have an "Deals" that is an array, and in the array you have objects with categoryID, title and tips.  You need to loop through each object in the array and print the result in the <li> tags

Comment: yes what i have to print in <li> is title and when clicked on particular title it has to show the tips in next page

Comment: without json format of data can we print in list using echo $row['categoryID'] ;
echo $row['title'];

Comment: yes, that can work as well

Comment: but how to use that in my code, can you please help me

Comment: hello C.S can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

As C.S. says, you don't need to use JSON, just loop through your array and add your list items.

**Edited to show basic use of PDO, and demo how to access query results.**

The `mysql_query` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, so you I would suggest you use [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)

First set up your database connection:

```
$dbName = "your_database_name_here";
$dbUserName = "your_username_here";
$dbPassword = "your_password_here";
$db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$dbName, $dbUserName, $dbPassword );
```

Then run your query, and echo your list (or whatever you need from the database by accessing the `$row` array within the `while` loop):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * from category");
$stmt->execute();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
     echo "<li>". $row['title'] ."</li>";
}
```

p.s. you should get rid of that inline css, it's a bad habit to get into.

Comment: hai daniel thanks for the reply but i have a doubt that how to give it in jquery mobile html page. Do i need to retrieve the data from database using the php in the same code where am printing that data, please tell me thanks

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: that's because $resultArray was undefined. It was just an example... I have edited to show a more detailed demo.

Comment: thanks daniel its working great i have one more doubt that when clicking those particular list element it has to go to another page and tips has to be displayed in thet page in list view form. How to do that?

Comment: hi daniel can you help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I don't get the impression that you are trying very hard.

Comment: First off - check your double/single quotes in the prepare statement (they are wrong). You need to look at prepared statements for the correct usage http://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements. You need to use something like `$stmt->bindParam(':id', $_GET['id']);` to bind your id value before you execute the query.

Comment: do i need to give like this <?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM REGISTRY where name = ?");
if ($stmt->execute(array($_GET['name']))) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
  }
}
?>

Comment: hi daniel thanks, i have tried in the following way $getID = $_GET['id'];
echo $getID;
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM category where categoryID = ?");
if ($stmt->execute(array($_GET['id']))) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
  }
} it is getting but i have to print it in list view but how to use this, can you please explain thanks.

Comment: sorry daniel anyway thanks i am able to print it. but i have one more doubt am having tips as ["45","46","47","48","49","50","51","52","53","54","55","56"] and in another table am having the tips as id 45 tip wash your eyes, id 46 tip dont rub your eyes how to split the array and according to that i have to get particular tip and to be printed any suggestions please.

Comment: If you have another question, you need to post it separately.